# Resolving locale in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to retrieve locale information in a Java application using this following line of code.

```
processor = new JQMenusTagProcessor(super.pageContext.getRequest().getLocale());
```

But the above piece of code always retrieve the default locale i.e en_GB.

How can I retireve the newly changed locale in my application which I am passing along with the url as shown below (as a request)

```
url?lang=fr
```

My application-context.xml file looks like as shown below:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
<property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"/>
<property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" /> 
<property name="cookieMaxAge" value="604800"/> 

<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
<property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
</bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Google for "Spring documentation". Click on the first link. Hit Ctrl-F and search for "locale". Click on the first link of the table of contents. Read the second sentence. I takes approximately 15 seconds to find the information. Also see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-arguments

Comment: After browsing in google,trying out several times and facing lot of errors only I have posted on SO to get some expert advise.These things I have tried fixes like using LocaleContextHolders and SessionLocaleResolver already but doesn't seem to work or may be because I am doing it in the wrong way.

Comment: From SO [tour](stackoverflow.com/tour) on posting good question : *Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do*. If you had said how you tried to use `SessionLocaleResolver` and what were your errors you would have better answers.

Comment: @user3767064: but you don't seem to follow the indications of the official documentation: use RequestContext.getLocale(), or add a Locale parameter to your methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. Getting the locale from the HttpServletRequest is NOT how the documentation says you should get the locale.

Comment: I am the one asking a question here sir and not getting any constructive help so far. Could you please remain specific to the question I have asked and comment accordingly.

Comment: I have tried that JB ..I will get back with the problems I have faced.Thanks for your suggestion.